# Turing machine to find maximum of an infinite set

Tags: turing-machines, computability, uncountability

Given a set that is infinite but still countable, does a TM exist that goes over every element in the set and finds the maximum?
Is this a computable function?

Comment: How is the set specified? The standard Turing machine can only take inputs of finite length.

Comment: the set is an enumeration of all total computable functions, so it is infinite but still countable

Comment: Over what domain is the set? I.e, is it a set of natural numbers? Of real numbers? Complex numbers?

Comment: There is no maximum in an infinite set of natural numbers. Computing the supremum (which always exists) is trivially easy in this case: always output $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, no, this is not possible. It depends on how the infinite set is represented. (I'm assuming it's a set of integers.)

The usual way to represent a possibly-infinite set $S$ is as a Turing machine $M$: $M$ enumerates all the elements of $S$. For this representation, it is uncomputable to determine the maximum element of $S$. That is, on input $\langle M \rangle$, determining the maximum element enumerated by $M$ is uncomputable. This can be proven using Rice's theorem.

There are other ways to represent possibly-infinite sets, though. The most common is using logical formulas. If the set $S$ is given by a formula $\varphi$ in some logic $\mathcal{L}$ where $S = \{w : \varphi(w)\}$, then determining the maximum element of the set $S$ *may* be computable if the logic $\mathcal{L}$ is simple enough. For example, if $\mathcal{L}$ is linear arithmetic (basically only addition, "and", "or", "not", $<$, and $=$), then determining the maximum is computable (returning $\infty$ if there is no maximum). But if $\mathcal{L}$ also has multiplication, then it's uncomputable.

Comment: A Turing Machine can encode also finite sets. And anyways, and infinite set over the integers doesn't have a maximum - so its trivially easy to compute (output $\infty$ immediately)

Comment: @nirshahar I changed it to "integers" and "possibly infinite" which is what I had in mind. Your statement is technically incorrect but I assume you mean "over the positive integers".

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, let me know if you notice anything wrong in the answer now.